# Python, override inherited method's functionality

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I have the following class.

```py
class PlotOnMap:

    def __init__(self, lat_lon_a, lat_lon_b, optimal, f_map=None):
        self.lat_lon_a = lat_lon_a
        self.lat_lon_b = lat_lon_b
        self.optimal = optimal
        self.f_map = f_map

    def create_map(self):
        """
        This function creates a map with folium, centered with the location of the three given points.
        """
        self.f_map = folium.Map([midlat, midlon], zoom_start=12)

    def plot_gdt_and_triangulation(self):
        """
        This function plots the locations given by the users with markers and create an heat map of the triangulation.
        """
        # plot the gdt's locations.
        folium.Marker(
            location=gdt1,
            popup='GDT 1',
            icon=folium.Icon()
        ).add_to(self.f_map)
        folium.Marker(
            location=gdt2,
            popup='GDT 2',
            icon=folium.Icon()
        ).add_to(self.f_map)
        folium.Marker(
            location=uav,
            popup='Target Area.',
            icon=folium.Icon()
        ).add_to(self.f_map)

        # plot the triangulation (regular and optimal) area
        plugins.HeatMap(data=self.lat_lon_a,
                        ).add_to(self.f_map)
        plugins.HeatMap(data=self.lat_lon_b,
                        ).add_to(self.f_map)
        plugins.HeatMap(data=self.optimal,
                        gradient={0.65: 'lime'}
                        ).add_to(self.f_map)
```

And I'm inheriting it:

```py
class Plot2ndPosition(PlotOnMap):

    def __init__(self, lat_lon_a, lat_lon_b, optimal):
        self.plot_on_map = super().__init__(lat_lon_a, lat_lon_b, optimal)

    def plot_map(self):
        return self.plot_on_map.create_map()

    def plot_locations(self):
        return self.plot_on_map.plot_gdt_and_triangulation()
```

the only difference is, that in the Plot2ndPosition class, in the second method, I don't wan't to plot gdt2 and the heat maps, I want to plot only gdt1 and and uav (first and last markers).

I thought about something in the direction of assigning each to a variable and somehow omitting it when I inherit the method.

```py
    def plot_gdt_and_triangulation(self):
        """
        This function plots the locations given by the users with markers and create an heat map of the triangulation.
        """
        # plot the gdt's locations.
        one = folium.Marker(
            location=gdt1,
            popup='GDT 1',
            icon=folium.Icon()
        )

        one.add_to(self.f_map)
        two = folium.Marker(
            location=gdt2,
            popup='GDT 2',
            icon=folium.Icon()
        )
        two.add_to(self.f_map)

        three = folium.Marker(
            location=uav,
            popup='Target Area.',
            icon=folium.Icon()
        )
        three.add_to(self.f_map)

        # plot the triangulation (regular and optimal) area
        trian_plot1 = plugins.HeatMap(data=self.lat_lon_a,
                        ).add_to(self.f_map)
        trian_plot2 = plugins.HeatMap(data=self.lat_lon_b,
                        ).add_to(self.f_map)
        trian_plot3 = plugins.HeatMap(data=self.optimal,
                        gradient={0.65: 'lime'}
                        ).add_to(self.f_map)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to override `plot_gdt_and_triangulation()` in `Plot2ndPosition`

```
class Plot2ndPosition(PlotOnMap):

    def __init__(self, lat_lon_a, lat_lon_b, optimal):
        super().__init__(lat_lon_a, lat_lon_b, optimal)

    def plot_gdt_and_triangulation(self):
        folium.Marker(
            location=gdt1,
            popup='GDT 1',
            icon=folium.Icon()
        ).add_to(self.f_map)
        folium.Marker(
            location=uav,
            popup='Target Area.',
            icon=folium.Icon()
        ).add_to(self.f_map)
```

You can also remove `plot_map()`, it just call `create_map()`. You can use `Plot2ndPosition` instance to call it. And in case you have more logic there you don't need to save the base class as a member, all its methods are already available from `self`

```
def plot_map(self):
    return self.create_map()
```